# Can one have $f(n)\sim \frac{a}{\sqrt{n}}$ as $n\to\infty$ but $\frac{f(n-1)}{f(n)}= 1+\frac{k}{n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right) $ with $k\neq\frac12$?

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

In the course of exploring the values of a family of games, I needed to solve a non-linear recursion.  The approach taken was an asymptotic expansion in $n$, the index in this family of the game being valued.

The equation in question is 
$$
a_n = \frac{3a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}+4a_{n-1}a_{n-2}}{2+6a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}+8a_{n-1}a_{n-2}}
$$
with $a_1 = a_2 = \frac16$.

Having done some perturbation theory I have been able to obtain a starting point 
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{n}} +\frac{5}{8n} + \frac{f_n}{n}
$$
where as long as $f_n$ goes to zero satisfies the recursion equation up to and including order $n^{-2}$.  $f_n$ cannot be identically zero, since then the recursion will read $\frac{9}{64}n^{-5/2} = 0$.

That $\frac{9}{64}n^{-5/2}$ has proven very hard to cancel by trying various forms for $a_n$.  For example, if you replace the $\frac{1}{4\sqrt{n}}$ by 
a sum of more complicated terms containing adjustable parameters, and adjust the parameters to force cancellation at orders up to $n^{-2}$, the contribution to the  $n^{-5/2}$ term seem always to cancel out, leaving that $\frac{9}{64}n^{-5/2} $ intact.  I've tried a large number of times along these lines.

A bit of work with the series (expanded in $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$) representing the recursion, expressed in terms of $f_n$, leads me to try an assumption that 
$$
f_{n-1} = f_n(1+k/n+r/n^2\ldots)\\
f_{n-2} = f_n(1+2k/n+s/n^2\ldots)\\
$$ 
which allows the $f_n/n^2$ term to cancel the $\frac{9}{64}n^{-5/2} $ if
$$
f_n = \frac{51}{160\sqrt{n}} + o(n^{-1/2} )
$$ and $$
k = \frac{47}{34}
$$

But that involves finding some $f(n)$ that falls as $\frac{a}{\sqrt{n}}$ while the expansion of $f(n-1)$ is $f(n)(1+ \frac{47}{34n} + \ldots)$.  Typical functions, such as $n^{-1/2}$, yield $\frac12$ in place of that $\frac{47}{34}$.

So the question:

**Can there be any $f(n)$ such that $f(n) \to \frac{a}{\sqrt{n}}$ as $n->\infty$, but $\frac{f(n-1)}{f(n)}\to 1+\frac{k}{n} + O(1/n^2)$ with $k\neq\frac12$?**

And if there cannot be, can you prove that?

Comment: By $f(n) \to \frac{a}{\sqrt{n}}$, do you mean $f(n) \sim \frac{a}{\sqrt{n}}$, i.e. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)\sqrt{n}}{a} = 1$?

Comment: The answer is no. To see why, note that, if $\frac{f(n-1)}{f(n)}=1+\frac{k}n+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$ then $\frac{(n-1)^kf(n-1)}{n^kf(n)}=1+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$, that is, $\frac{(n-1)^kf(n-1)}{n^kf(n)}=e^{g(n)}$ for every $n$, with $|g(n)|\leqslant\frac{C}{n^2}$ for some finite $C$. Thus, $n^kf(n)=f(1)\prod\limits_{i=2}^n\frac{i^kf(k)}{(i-1)^kf(i-1)}=f(1)e^{-G(n)}$ with $G(n)=\sum\limits_{i=2}^ng(i)$. The series $\sum\limits_ig(i)$ converges absolutely hence $G(n)\to G_\infty$ and $f(n)\sim f(1)e^{-G_\infty}\frac1{n^k}$. In particular, ...

Comment: ... if $f(n)\sim\frac{a}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $\frac{f(n-1)}{f(n)}=1+\frac{k}n+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$ then $k=\frac12$.

Comment: Looks like @Did proof is right.  Too bad for me.  BTW, empirically, $f_n$ falls like roughly $n^{-0.41}$ for the sparticular starting values of $a_1=a_2 = \frac16$

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing an answer so as to get this off the "unanswered" list.

Because there is no way to cancel the $-\frac9{64}n^{-5/2}$ using an ordinary exmansion in powers of $n^{-1/2}$ I ended up having to move outside that box.  After a staggering number of tries using expressions like $a_n = \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{n+\beta}} + \frac{\gamma}{n+\delta} $, which all led to the same failure to cancel the $-\frac9{64}n^{-5/2}$, I finally looked at multiplying the next term by the harmonic number $H_n$.

In this way, it turns out that with the next term, the perturbation series is 
$$
a_n = \frac1{4\sqrt{n}}+\frac5{8n}-\frac9{32}\frac{H_n}{n^{3/2}}
$$
where $$H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k$$

Since this brough my agreement with numerical calculations into the part per trillion range wor modest values of $n$, this is good enough to satisfy my obsession with going to the next term.